# How can I get some of the Django ORM benefits of using a ForeignKey without actually using one?

Tags: django, orm

I have models that look like this (simplified of course):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = Charfield(max_length=30)

class Change(models.Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
```

My problem is that this won't work, because Products get deleted, but I need the reference in Change to remain (using on.delete to set it to null is not an option). So I have switched it to:

```
class Change(models.Model):
    product = CharField(max_length=30)
```

But now I have lost the benefits of a Foreign Key field when querying. When I query for a change, I cannot select_related for Products or do any other join type action without digging into `extra` type clauses.

So my question, is there any good way to have my cake and eat it too? To be able to join on the field easily, but not have it be an FK? Seems like there must be some way besides FK type to say that fields are related. Perhaps through a manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this exact problem at hand... regrettably its priory was bumped pretty far down my list. However, I believe I have actually used a many-to-many field to retain a link in a different part of my application.  Using the many-to-many field seems to address all of the issues I had come across.  See my simplified models below.

With this setup I am able to:

- Create a Card and link a number of Card_Tests to it (note that there can be duplicates)
- Modify or Remove any one or all of the Card_Tests without it removing the Card's record.
- Remove all of the Card_Tests by deleting the Card record.

**Card Model**

```
class Card(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    card_tests = models.ManyToManyField('Card_Test', through='Card_Test_List')
```

**Through Model**

```
class Card_Test_List(models.Model):
    card_id = models.ForeignKey('Card')
    card_test_id = models.ForeignKey('Card_Test')
    result       = models.TextField()
```

**Card Test Model**

```
class Card_Test(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Right, but that would still leave me with the same (possibly unsolvable) problem, which is that I want to be able to delete Card and not delete Card_Test.

Comment: @zenWeasel: Just to clarify, you want the FK relationship, but want to be able to delete *either* record and the other record stay intact?  If it is a one way deletion you're after, in my example could you not reverse the rolls of the Card Test and Card?

Comment: Yes and No. My Change record would never get deleted, it's an audit trail type thing, but basically yes, I need deletes of either record to not cascade down to the other. I realize that is essentially asking a ForeignKey to not be a ForeignKey. So it's a funky edge case.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a boolean flag `deleted` to the `Product` model. When you wish to 'delete' a product, set `product.deleted=True` instead of deleting from the database. That would allow you to use a regular foreign key from `Change` to `Product`.

I don't know whether this would be suitable for your project. You might have to change quite a lot of code, e.g. replace `Product.objects.all()` with `Product.objects.exclude(deleted=True)`. Creating a manager where the queryset returns non-deleted items would help.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_code = Charfield(max_length=30)
    deleted = BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)

class Change(models.Model):
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
```

Comment: I think that would probably work for a lot of people but we actually already use a sys_delete flag for items that have history records attached. The products we need to delete, we actually need to delete and remove their other children. But that is sort of an oddity of my situation.